# How can I have 2 rows and 3 columns of desktops/workpaces in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces

How can I have 2 rows and 3 columns of desktops in Lubuntu? (Instead of having 1 row which is the default setting.) I haven't found a setting, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With LXDE the fine adjustment of desktop appearance is reduced as compared to other non-light weight desktops. Therefore by using **Desktop Pager** for workplace management you will only be able to set the number of desktops but not their appearance in rows and columns.

Still, if you desperately need this there is a way to disyplay 2 rows of desktop icons in the panel by increasing the panel height from the *Panel Settings* (right click on the panel to open) to a value of lager than 40 pixels:

[image]

To toggle between workspaces when moving the mouse to the screen borders you may be interested in [brightside](http://packages.ubuntu.com/brightside) [image: Install brightside] that is called with the command `brightside` from a terminal or by putting in autostart.

```
brightside-properties
```

sets the application's options.

Comment: Brightside is a great suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

There is a CLI that allows you to arrange the layout of your workspaces in LXDE. Unfortunately it doesn't update the mini-map in the panel -- the panel still displays one row of workspaces (Takkat's answer affects the panel, but I don't like the overall effect on the rest of the panel.)

Here's the answer over on Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/347528/openbox-make-4-desktops-2x2

To recap (and expound on) the solution here:

1. In the Openbox Configuration Manager, set your total # of desktops (e.g. 6)
2. Go to tmp dir: `cd /tmp/`
3. Download [setlayout.c](http://openbox.org/dist/tools/setlayout.c): `wget http://openbox.org/dist/tools/setlayout.c`
4. Install dependencies: `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`
5. Compile it: `gcc setlayout.c -o setlayout -lX11`
6. Copy it to /usr/local/bin as you'll need to run the setlayout command after reboot: `sudo cp setlayout /usr/local/bin`
7. Set your layout geometry: `setlayout 0 3 2 0` (for a 3x2 grid)

With this grid setting, `CTRL-ALT-<Arrowkey>` navigate properly. Here's the workspaces with a 2x2 layout:

[image: Workspace switcher notification icon]

And dragging windows across workspaces with the mouse (or with `Alt-Shift-<Arrowkey>`) works as expected (up/down/left/right)

**FYI #1** The program prints usage help if four args aren't passed:

```
The first is layout, 0 is horizontal and 1 is vertical.
Second and third is number of desks horizontally and vertically.
The last is starting corner, 0 = topleft, 1 = topright,
                             2 = bottomright, 3 = bottomleft.
```

**FYI #2** Alternate download link for setlayout.c: http://hastebin.com/pizabalefo.tex

**FYI #3** When changing the layout later to a different number of desktops, first set your layout back to a single row (e.g. 1x6) using `setlayout 0 6 1 0` before opening the configuration manager, or it may crash.

Comment: The setlayout tool shows a grid in the notification widget, but the up/down shortcuts don't work for me, only the left/right, as if they were all in a line.  Strangely, I can drag windows to the workspaces up or down, but the shortcuts don't work.