# Make LXDE shortcuts more like Unity

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, lxde, openbox

I recently switched from Unity desktop to LXDE desktop (it's easy to install in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`.)

That's all good, but I'm irritated by a few keyboard and mouse shortcuts that are slightly different in LXDE vs Unity. These are:

```
| Action:                          | In Unity:             | In LXDE:          |
|----------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------|
| Navigate workspaces              | Ctrl-Alt-Arrow        | Ctrl-Alt-Arrow    |
| Navigate and take focused window | Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Arrow  | Alt-Shift-Arrow ! |
| Mouse-drag to move a Window      | Alt-LeftButton        | Alt-LeftButton    |
| Mouse-drag to resize a Window    | Alt-MiddleButton      | Alt-RightButton ! |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

You can see how some of the actions have the same shortcut, while others have a different shortcut (`!`), which is just irritating.

Since I'm moving from Unity to LXDE, I'd like to change the LXDE shortcuts to match Unity.

Answer (score 2):

In LXDE (which runs OpenBox), edit your `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to change the above actions.

*Note:* After changing the openbox config xml file, you'll have to reconfigure openbox by running: `openbox --reconfigure`

**For the window / workspace action:**

We want to change the `Shift-Alt-[ArrowKey]` keyboard actions to `Ctrl-Shift-Alt-[ArrowKey]` to match Unity.

In the `<keyboard>` section of the xml file, find the keybindings with the `SendToDesktop` actions. These are bound to `S-A-Left` (shift-alt-left), right, up, and down. Change the bindings to `C-S-A-Left` (crel-shift-alt-left), right, up, and down. e.g.

```
<keybind key="C-S-A-Left">
  <action name="SendToDesktop">
    <to>left</to>
    <wrap>no</wrap>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-S-A-Right">
  <action name="SendToDesktop">
    <to>right</to>
    <wrap>no</wrap>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-S-A-Up">
  <action name="SendToDesktop">
    <to>up</to>
    <wrap>no</wrap>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-S-A-Down">
  <action name="SendToDesktop">
    <to>down</to>
    <wrap>no</wrap>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

**For the mouse / window-resize action:**

We want to change the mouse's middle click-drag-on-window action to resize (to match Unity).

In the `<mouse>` section, under the `<context name="Frame">` section of the xml file, find the mouse drag bindings for the Middle buttons, and change it to:

```
  <mousebind button="A-Middle" action="Press">
    <action name="Resize"/>
  </mousebind>
```

You can change the `name="A-Right" action="Drag"` setting if you like - it is setup as the above.

**Bonus #1: Shift print-screen to capture an area**

I don't recall if this is in Unity by default, but I really love `Shift-Print` to select and capture an area of the screen with the mouse. I also like using the program Shutter to accomplish this. Here's a keybinding for that (place in the `<keyboard>` section of the xml file.)

```
<keybind key="S-Print">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>shutter -s</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

**Bonus #2:** If you're interested in making the LXDE workspaces into a grid, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44267/how-can-i-have-2-rows-and-3-columns-of-desktops-workpaces-in-lubuntu/776962#776962).